# Codeigniter active records: like and where in SQL statement

Tags: codeigniter

I need to select several rows that respect these conditions:

1. date >= today
2. keyword present in fields 1, 2 or 3

i guess the SQL statement for this should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE date >= '2010-09-12' AND (field1 LIKE '%keyword%' OR field2 LIKE '%keyword%' OR field3 LIKE '%keyword%')
```

I am trying to write this using codeigniter's active records, but the the LIKE condition seems to override the date one.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('venues', 'events.venue = venue_id');

//first condition: date >= today
$this->db->where('date >=', date('Y-m-d'));

if ($keyword)
//if keyword is present, add this condition as well
{
    $this->db->like('events.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('band', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('venues.venue', $keyword);
}

$this->db->order_by('date', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('events.priority', 'DESC'); 
$Q = $this->db->get('events');
```

I probably need to insert the LIKE statement inside a parentesis, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to write the 'like'-part of your query this way:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('venues', 'events.venue = venue_id');

if ($keyword)
//if keyword is present, add this condition as well
{
   $where = "( events.description LIKE '$keyword' OR band LIKE '$keyword' OR venues.venue LIKE '$keyword')";
   $this->db->where($where);

}
//first condition: date >= today
$this->db->where('date >=', date('Y-m-d'));

$this->db->order_by('date', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('events.priority', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('title' => $match, 'page1' => $match, 'page2' => $match);

$this->db->like($array);

// WHERE title LIKE '%match%' AND page1 LIKE '%match%' AND page2 LIKE '%match%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Linkearray = array('page_content' => $search, 'page_title' => $search);
$this->db->like($Linkearray);
$this->db->where('page_online',1);
$this->db->where('page_site',$page_site);

// WHERE page_content LIKE '% my Text%' 
// AND page_title LIKE '% my page title %' 
// AND page_online = '1' and page_site ='29'
```